# How to use code first migrations with Azure App Service

Tags: entity-framework, azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-web-app-service

When I run locally I run the commands below manually and then package and publish the app onto my IIS server.

```
Add-Migration Initial
Update-Database
```

When I want to publish to an azure appservice will these commands run automatically? If so how does it know to use a different ConnectionString when I publish it to azure?

I added the connectionString for azure in appsettings.json but I don't understand how I can tell my controllers etc to use that when I publish to azure AppServices

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "AzureTestConnection": "Data Source=tcp:xxxxxx-test.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=xxxxx;User Id=xxx@yyyy.database.windows.net;Password=xxxxxx",
    "NWMposBackendContext": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=NWMposBackendContext-573f6261-6657-4916-b5dc-1ebd06f7401b;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }
```

I am trying to have three profiles with different connection strings

1. Local
2. Published to AzureApp-Test
3. Published to AzureApp-Prod

Comment: Do you ensure that your website is asp.net not asp.net core?

Comment: its ASP.net CORE for sure that's what I want to use, does that matter?

Comment: No matter, I just for confirm, because the web app do not have appsetting.json.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When I want to publish to an azure appservice will these commands run automatically?

EF does not support Automatic migrations, you may need to manually execute Add-Migration or dotnet ef migrations add for adding migration files. You could explicitly execute the command to apply the migrations, also you could [apply migrations in your code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50243829/how-to-apply-database-code-first-migrations-in-an-azure-deployed-application/50248545#50248545).

And you could add the following code in the Configure method of Startup.cs file:

```
using (var scope = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
{
    scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>().Database.Migrate();
}
```

> I am trying to have three profiles with different connection strings

You would dynamically choose a connection string based on Environment, so here is main steps, you could refer to it.

1. Set the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT value to azure in webapp>property>debug.

[image]

2.Follow [ASP.NET Core MVC with Entity Framework Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50401449/trying-to-get-net-core-application-working-on-azure/50406383#50406383) to get started.

3.Set the appsetting.json with your two connection string.

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "connectiondefault",
    "azure": "connectionazure"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  }
}
```

**Note**:You could also set the connectionstring in database  on portal to here, then you could test it in local and could use debug to troubleshooting.

Also, you could try to **test with one connectionstring** to ensure you have no problem with connecting to database.

4.Enable Developer exception page by using `app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();` and the `app.UseExceptionHandler` methods in your startup class which would display the errors.

```
        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .Build();

            HostingEnvironment = env;
        }

        public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }
        public IHostingEnvironment HostingEnvironment { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            if (HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                services.AddDbContext<SchoolContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            }
            else
            {
                services.AddDbContext<SchoolContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("azure")));
            }
            services.AddMvc();
        }
```

For more details, you could refer to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50401449/trying-to-get-net-core-application-working-on-azure/50406383#50406383).

Comment: where do I find this option? Set the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT value to azure in webapp>property>debug

Comment: You could set it in local as I have said, right click your app and click property>debug. When you publish to azure, the setting also apply.

Comment: Yes but I don't only have debug profile, I need multiple profiles, not just development and production, I don't see how I can add more environments in your solution, like Test, Dev, QA, Prod

Comment: I know you have multiple profiles. The ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT value is represent the current profile you want to use. And all your profile with different settings is in ConfigureServices.  When your ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT value is test, it will make judgement and go to the test connectionstring.

Comment: I understand that, but I don't understand where I add the environments

Comment: What's the meaning of environments you want to add?

Comment: you call it profile I think, for Test profile I want use connection string 1, for dev profile I want use connection string 2, but where do I add those profiles?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171595/discussion-between-joey-cai-and-matt-douhan).